# Refreshing computed class properties in swift

Tags: swift

The model class `Snake` has 2 properties `length` and `body`, and a delegate, with a method `getSnakeBody()` that returns the body (of type `Body`). I want the `body` property to get updated every time the `length` property gets updated. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
class Snake {
    var delegate: SnakeShower?
    var body: Body? { return delegate?.getSnakeBody() }
    var length: Int = 1 { didSet { /* update the body property */ } }
}
```

Comment: Well, how about delegate?.setLength(newValue) ?

Comment: Unrelated, `body` should be an optional, since `delegate` could conceivably be nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Swift documentation:

> In addition to stored properties, classes, structures, and
>   enumerations can define computed properties, which do not actually
>   store a value. Instead, they provide a getter and an optional setter
>   to retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly.

Which means that every time the computed property is accessed to be read, the code from the brackets is being executed. 
You might have not formulated correctly the statement of the problem, or some details are lacking there.